# How to show a link with .html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting text from a REST api in the form of JSON. I show this data like this:

```
$("#mytext").html(item.text);
```

However, sometimes this text is too long. When this happens I want to show subset of the text with a `...more` link at the end. The more link will take users to another page.

I'm doing this:

```
if (item.text.length > 100)
  $("#mytext").html(item.text.substring(0,95)"+"....");  
else 
  $("#mytext").html(item.text);
```

How can I append the more link? the link would need to go to `/moreinfo/${item.id}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a more link like this -

```
if (item.text.length > 100)
  $("#mytext").html(item.text.substring(0,95)+"...."+"<span class='more'>more</span>");  
else 
  $("#mytext").html(item.text);
```

and on click of more link, show full text -

```
$(document.body).on('click','.more',function(){
  $("#mytext").html(item.text);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would refrain from using `.html`. If you are only dealing with text why not use `.text()`? You'll only thank yourself later if you ever run into potential bugs from parsing straight strings without protection.

Try this.

```
if (item.text.length > 100) {
  $('#mytext').text(item.text.substring(0, 95));
  $('<span>more</span>').appendTo($('#mytext'));
} else {
  $('#mytext').text(item.text);
}
$('#mytext span').click(function () {
  $('#mytext').text(item.text);
});
```

I'm sure there has to be a way to nicely animate this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var url = "/moreinfo/${item.id}";
$("#mytext").html(item.text.substring(0,95)+"....<a href='"+url+"'>more</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the  element in there

ie.

```
$("#mytext").html(item.text.substring(0,95)"+"....<a href=\"/moreinfo/"+item.id+"\">more</a>");
```